# Unable to access custom serverless API on Vercel using self-hosted GitHub repository

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, backend, vercel

**Problem Description:**

I am trying to utilize the following API from GitHub: https://github.com/philippdormann/elternportal-api. However, the URL pointing to the serverless function on Vercel, which belongs to the owner of this project, seems to be non-functional. Therefore, I took the initiative to set up the project myself and created a new Vercel project to deploy the API as a serverless function there.

**Steps Taken:**

1. Cloned the GitHub repository to my local machine.
2. Created a new Vercel project to host the API as a serverless function.
3. Created a new folder named "api" in my cloned GitHub project.

**Issue Encountered:**

Although the API is successfully deployed after specifying the "api" folder as the build container in the Vercel project settings, attempting to access the API through the provided URL from Vercel results in the following error:

> 404: NOT_FOUND
> Code: NOT_FOUND
> ID: fra1::f8nc5-1690471908055-a1306775d446

**Additional Information:**

I came across suggestions from various sources (though I am uncertain of their validity) that specifying the "api" folder as the build container in the Vercel project settings would be the correct approach. While this method did lead to a successful deployment of the API, I am still unable to access it due to the mentioned error.

**Request for Assistance:**

I am seeking guidance on resolving the "404: NOT_FOUND" error and successfully accessing the API hosted as a serverless function on my Vercel project. Any insights or alternative solutions to correctly set up the project and access the API would be greatly appreciated.